# adding children groups dynamically using ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to reproduce dynamically the following static inventory:

```
novaclient ansible_connection=local

[masters]
192.168.13.236

[nodes]
192.168.13.201
192.168.13.237

[cluster:children]
masters
nodes
```

Reading the ansible documentation, the `add_host` module seems to be the right candidate as it is designed for *adding a host (and alternatively a group) to the ansible-playbook in-memory inventory*. Here is my playbook for doing that:

```
- hosts: all

  connection: local

  vars:
    ips_per_group:
      - ["masters", "192.168.13.236"]
      - ["nodes"  , "192.168.13.201"]
      - ["nodes"  , "192.168.13.237"]

  tasks:

    - name: add host dynamically
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item[1] }}"
        groups: "{{ item[0] }}" 
      loop: "{{ ips_per_group }}"

    - name: add masters and nodes groups to cluster group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item[0] }}"
        groups: "cluster"
      loop: "{{ ips_per_group }}"

    - name: test
      debug:
        var: groups
```

Running that playbook triggers the following warnings:

```
 [WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: masters
 [WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: nodes
```

As far as I understood, those warnings come from the fact that `masters` and `nodes` have not been declared as `children` of the `cluster` group. Trying the following syntax:

```
- name: add masters and nodes groups to cluster group
  add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: "cluster:children"
  loop:
    - masters
```

triggers the following warning due to the colon in the `groups` name:

```
 [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
```

Would you have any idea for doing that without any warnings ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use [group_by – Create Ansible groups based on facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_by_module.html#group-by-create-ansible-groups-based-on-facts). With the modified data structure, which makes the examples simpler, the plays below show how it works.

```yaml
    - name: 1.Create my_groups
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false

      vars:

        ips_per_group:
          192.168.13.236:
            my_groups: ['masters']
            my_children_group: 'cluster'
          192.168.13.201:
            my_groups: ['nodes']
            my_children_group: 'cluster'
          192.168.13.237:
            my_groups: ['nodes']
            my_children_group: 'cluster'

      tasks:

        - name: add host dynamically
          add_host:
            name: "{{ item.key }}"
            groups: "{{ item.value.my_groups }}" 
            group_children: "{{ item.value.my_children_group }}"
          loop: "{{ ips_per_group|dict2items }}"
        - debug:
            var: groups

    - name: 2.Create children for group masters
      hosts: masters
      gather_facts: false

      tasks:

        - name: add hosts to children groups
          group_by:
            key: "{{ group_children }}"
        - debug:
            var: groups

    - name: 3.Create children for group nodes
      hosts: nodes
      gather_facts: false

      tasks:

        - name: add hosts to children groups
          group_by:
            key: "{{ group_children }}"
        - debug:
            var: groups
    
    - name: 4.Test group cluster
      hosts: cluster
      gather_facts: false

      tasks:

        - debug:
            var: group_children
        - debug:
            var: groups
    
    - name: 5.Print groups
      hosts: localhost

      tasks:

        - debug:
            var: groups
```

Give (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [1.Create my_groups] ***
  ...
ok: [localhost] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]

PLAY [2.Create children for group masters] ***
  ...
ok: [192.168.13.236] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    cluster: [192.168.13.236]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]

PLAY [3.Create children for group nodes] ***
  ...
ok: [192.168.13.201] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    cluster: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]
ok: [192.168.13.237] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    cluster: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]

PLAY [4.Test group cluster] ***
  ...
ok: [192.168.13.236] => 
  group_children: cluster
ok: [192.168.13.201] => 
  group_children: cluster
ok: [192.168.13.237] => 
  group_children: cluster
  ...
ok: [192.168.13.236] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    cluster: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]
ok: [192.168.13.201] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    cluster: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]
ok: [192.168.13.237] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    cluster: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]

PLAY [5.Print groups] ***
  ...
ok: [localhost] => 
  groups:
    all: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237, localhost]
    cluster: [192.168.13.236, 192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    masters: [192.168.13.236]
    nodes: [192.168.13.201, 192.168.13.237]
    ungrouped: [localhost]
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was quite amazed it did not work when I tried your example and re-read the doc.

But after reading the [module's source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/add_host.py), I didn't really see anything that actually implements adding groups as children (or at least cleanly, hence the warning that comes from [the inventory data management class](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/d241794daa6d413e6447890e2a4f11e0d818cf0e/lib/ansible/inventory/data.py#L142))

But you can still achieve the desired result by adding hosts to all needed groups at once which will give the same result at the end (check the `groups` var with a static inventory containing children declaration, it's identical to the one I provide below)

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ips_per_group:
      - ["masters", "192.168.13.236"]
      - ["nodes"  , "192.168.13.201"]
      - ["nodes"  , "192.168.13.237"]

  tasks:
    - name: Add host dynamically
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item[1] }}"
        groups:
          - "{{ item[0] }}"
          - cluster
      loop: "{{ ips_per_group }}"

    - name: See result
      debug:
        var: groups
```

Note that if you still want to keep this in separate tasks and take advantage of the already created groups as children, you could do it like this:

```
  tasks:

    - name: Add host dynamically
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item[1] }}"
        groups:
          - "{{ item[0] }}"
      loop: "{{ ips_per_group }}"

    - name: Add masters and nodes to cluster group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups:
          - cluster
      loop: "{{ ['masters', 'nodes'] |
        map('extract', groups) |
        list | flatten | unique }}"
```

Whatever solution you choose, this is the resulting groups (provided you have an empty inventory at start)

```
TASK [See result] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "groups": {
        "all": [
            "192.168.13.236",
            "192.168.13.201",
            "192.168.13.237"
        ],
        "cluster": [
            "192.168.13.236",
            "192.168.13.201",
            "192.168.13.237"
        ],
        "masters": [
            "192.168.13.236"
        ],
        "nodes": [
            "192.168.13.201",
            "192.168.13.237"
        ],
        "ungrouped": []
    }
}
```

Comment: your solutions match exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot